# How do I tear out the existing menu in a theme and replace it with super-fish (v7.x)

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I know this is similar to the Bartik/menu question but I do not believe it is the same, here is the requirement. I am using "the morning after" theme in Drupal 7. This theme looks the way the client wants it but we need a drop-down ability on the "main menu", the menu that runs horizontally across the top of the page. This theme does not have a "navigation", "main menu" or similar region to pop super-fish into. I have tried all the instructions in the Bartik/Super-fish post and I can get super-fish to show up in an region but I have not been able to get it to REPLACE the existing embedded-in-the-theme menu. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This site would not let me post an answer, so as an edit, here is the answer I found.
This did not get me 100% where I wanted but found this on another post. It is for a different theme but it seemed to be essentially the same. hope it helps

Im using Drupal 7 with the Busy Theme and I can't figure out how to set Superfish to replace the existing main menu with itself. I can add Superfish to other regions of the theme and it works great, but there is no way to replace the main menu with Superfish that I can find. This may be a problem in that the main menu area of Busy doesn't seem to have a region set to it, so perhaps that could be the problem...

Thoughts? I want to use a drop-down menu for the main user menu, but nothing I do will allow Superfish to replace that main menu.

Description Login or register to post comments Comments

1
Posted by Mehrpadin on April 1, 2011 at 7:54pm Hey there,

Well, normally you should ask the theme developer, but as I see there are a number of similar requests in the issue tracker of the theme, I think I should help you myself:

Create a new region by putting the code below somewhere in busy.info regions[navigation] = Navigation You may need to rebuild your theme registry. /templates/page.tpl.php , line #52 to #58: $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'clearfix')))); ?> Replace with this:
Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Superfish will not override your theme's main menu. The only way is to make its block and place it on some region.

You can replace the theme's menu variable/function with a region variable in your page.tpl.php following a guide [here](https://drupal.org/node/1088718).